# Copy and paste data frame - from R! to Writer/Word

Tags: r

Suppose I have some analysis results in data frame/table.
I wish to embed them in text document.

In case of LaTeX, I can use miscFuncs package:

```
library('miscFuncs')
latextable(myDataFrame)
```

and simply copy output displayed in R console and paste it to LaTeX document.

What if I wish to copy from R! output and paste to LibreOffice Writer or MS Word documents?

I think that most (?) convenient way is to generate output as tab-delimited text.
After pasting text, just convert them to table.

I know that there are functions which writes output to tab-delimited files:
http://www.instantr.com/2012/12/11/exporting-a-dataset-from-r/

so I guess there must be function/package which simply generate tab-delimited content?

---

Note - there was similar question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90184/can-i-copy-output-from-r-to-word-or-excel

but answers suggest to export content to delimited file. I wish to avoid this step.

Comment: In the answer to the "similar question" `write.csv(df, "clipboard", row.names = FALSE)` exports the answer in delimited form to the **clipboard**, not a disk file. From the clipboard you can paste directly into MS Word - I do it that way most days.

Comment: This seems most appropriate answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a data.frame, to me the easiest way is using `kable()` in `knitr` package, then copy-paste from console to spreadsheet

```
library(dplyr) # just to use the handy %>%
matrix(c(1:20), 5) %>% # some data
  as.data.frame() %>% # as it is a matrix, I need it as data.frame
  knitr::kable() # It is now tabulated, you can use in your Office software "convert text to table"
```

I you don't like the %>%,

```
knitr::kable(
  as.data.frame(
    matrix(c(1:20), 5)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way is to simply use a monospace font, such a Courier New or Lucida Console (for a couple of examples) in your word processor  -- if it looks okay on screen in your R session, it will look very similar in Libre Office's Writer or Word. A straight copy-paste from the R console to the document works fine once it's in a suitable font.

If you're trying to "reproduce the look" of the R session, this works quite well; if you're trying to format output for a paper or some-such it may be less suitable, depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using a intermediate file to save your table, you could use functions from the package `flextable` (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html).

Repex:

```
library(flextable)
# create a flextable object
ft <- flextable::flextable(data = head(iris))
# save it as a .docx file on your disk
flextable::save_as_docx(ft, path = "./test.docx")
# or pop-up a word window with your table
print(ft, preview ="docx") # from https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/117#issuecomment-487126438
```

Output:

[image: view of the table inside the test.docx file]

Now you can copy/paste this table inside your main document. Note that you can do a lot of customization with `flextable` and save your table in different output format like HTML or even .pptx.